# Why don't we have hair on palms?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy

We have hair all over the body except palms.
What is the biological reason behind this?

Answer (score 7):

The main functional reason is we need to be able to grip things with our hands (and feet, which are also hairless), and hair would interfere with that. Physiologically, the epidermis in these parts of the body is very thick and highly keratinized, and when combined with the thick underlaying layer of dermis, this results in skin that does not support the growth and maturation of hair follicles.

Comment: A support for that is that other hairy animals also don't have hair on their 'gripping surfaces' - palms of other primates and feet of mammals and birds.